# How to do 'If data is all tabs ( \t ) don't print row'?

Tags: php, regex

How to do 'If data is all tabs don't print row'?

If I don't want to print rows that ONLY contain tabs, how should I change my code?

I was thinking of using preg_match somehow, ie `preg_match('#(/\t+/)#',$lines[$i])`

But that will break my code since its turning a tab-delimited file into a table, removing the opening `<tr>` tag makes it work that way (no tab rows), but I can't put a class on the `<tr>` then.

PHP:

```
    echo "<table id='schedule_table'>"; 

//split into array by return\linefeed
$lines=explode("\r\n",$file);
//replace digits with class
$lines=preg_replace('#(\d+)#','<span class="table_digit">$1</span>',$lines);
//loop through rows
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) 
{ 
//if not blank then print row
if($lines[$i]!=""&&$lines[$i]!=" "&&$lines[$i]!=null)
    {
    echo "<tr class='schedule_row' value='$lines[$i]'>";
    //if row is 0 cell type is header
    $cell_type="td";
    $cell_class="schedule_cell";
    if($i==0)
    {
        $cell_type="th";
        $cell_class="schedule_hcell";
    }
    //end if

    //split into array by tabs
    $items=explode("\t",$lines[$i]);
    //loop through cells 
    for($j=0;$j<count($items);$j++) 
    { 
        //if not blank then print cell
        if($items[$j]!=""&&$items[$j]!=" ")
            {
            echo "<$cell_type class=$cell_class>".$items[$j]."</$cell_type>"; 
            }
    } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
    }
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor your regex:

```
preg_match('/^\t+$/', $line)
```

use this regex in your code as:

```
if ($lines[$i]!="" && $lines[$i]!=" " && !preg_match('/^\t+$/', $line[$i]))
```

Comment: so I tried that here but it didn't work.:

`$temp=preg_match("/^\t+$/gi",$lines[$i]);
//if not blank then print row
if($lines[$i]!=""&&$lines[$i]!=" "&&$lines[$i]!=$temp)
{do code}`

Comment: Thanks much M42, that worked, that match says "match if from start of line all the tabs to end of line" right?